# windows 10 - how to associate "edit" for .cmd files to notepad++ in context menu?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, context-menu, windows-server-2019

I would like to be able to right-click on a .cmd file in win10 (or windows server 2019), choose `edit` and have notepad++ open the file. I have a mixture of file types (as in 'nix text files) that are accessed this way in a windows interface, hence the use of notepad++. Life was simpler when I could just do the same with .cmd files, literally decades ago with another text editor. I've recently had a shift in my working environment, and find myself working in windows again.

So, please don't post an "answer" that I should just look further down the context menu for `Edit with Notepad++`.  Clearly I need to refresh my knowledge of the newish nooks and crannies buried in the registry (which have definitely changed since last I looked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because I could not find a direct answer on stack exchange, and because there are so many low-quality answers that pop up elsewhere, and also so I don't have to waste so much time looking again for this again (note there are several embedded assumptions here, so this is only a hint):

open regedit as admin.

navigate to:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\edit\command`

replace `%SystemRoot%\System32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1`

with `"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1`

exit and test.

or save this as a .reg file and merge it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,\
  64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,\
  00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,00
```

This was actually tested on server 2019

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Comment: unlikely, but if the stars align correctly, I'll accept my own answer.

Comment: Thanks for leaving the tip!  That's how long it took for me to stumble across this again.  A bit less than 9 months.